# jQuery: Toggle active class in specific case

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code:

```js
$("ul li").click(function() {
  var target = $($(this).data("target"));
  $(".hidden").not(target).not(this.closest('ul')).removeClass("show");
  target.toggleClass("show");
  $(this).toggleClass("active"); // Doesn't work well.
})
```

```css
* {
  cursor: default;
}

li {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}

li:hover,
.active {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li data-target=".one">Link One</li>
  <li data-target=".two">Link Two</li>
  <li data-target=".three">Link Three</li>
</ul>

<div class="hidden one">
  Lorem Ipsum One
</div>

<ul class="hidden two">
  <li data-target=".two_one">Link Two One</li>
  <li data-target=".two_two">Link Two Two</li>
</ul>

<div class="hidden two_one">
  Lorem Ipsum Two One
</div>

<div class="hidden two_two">
  Lorem Ipsum Two Two
</div>

<div class="hidden three">
  Lorem Ipsum One
</div>
```

Generally, everything works. **But:** The toggle function for the `.active` class does not work well. Currently, if you click one link, and then the next link of the same navigation, then both links are `.active`. That does not make sense. Always only one link of a navigation should have this class.

Can somebody help me please? Would be very happy about that!

Comment: You should remove the active class from the previous element then add it to another element
toggle works only when you click on the same element again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're already carrying out similar logic with the `.hidden`s, you just need to adapt it to remove the `active` class from siblings of the clicked element:

```
$(this).siblings().not(this).removeClass('active');
$(this).toggleClass("active");
```

```js
$("ul li").click(function() {
  var target = $($(this).data("target"));
  $(".hidden").not(target).not(this.closest('ul')).removeClass("show");
  target.toggleClass("show");
  $(this).siblings().not(this).removeClass('active');
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
})
```

```css
* {
  cursor: default;
}

li {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}

li:hover,
.active {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li data-target=".one">Link One</li>
  <li data-target=".two">Link Two</li>
  <li data-target=".three">Link Three</li>
</ul>

<div class="hidden one">
  Lorem Ipsum One
</div>

<ul class="hidden two">
  <li data-target=".two_one">Link Two One</li>
  <li data-target=".two_two">Link Two Two</li>
</ul>

<div class="hidden two_one">
  Lorem Ipsum Two One
</div>

<div class="hidden two_two">
  Lorem Ipsum Two Two
</div>

<div class="hidden three">
  Lorem Ipsum One
</div>
```

Comment: <3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3

Comment: Ohhh, unfortunately, I just found a mistake. If you click "Link Two", then "Link Two One", then "Link One", then "Link Two" again, theeen "Link Two One" is still "active" – it shouldn't be like that. Do you know how to fix that?